# Description of filter $F$ generated by a subset $E$ of $\mathcal P(W)$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, filters

I am trying to solve exercises from the book [Modal Logic](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0521527147) by  Patrick Blackburn, Maarten de Rijke and Yde Venema. I am having a problem to solve one of the exercises in the section 2.5, the exercise is 2.5.1(b) in page 98. Please help me.

> **Exercise** :
>   Let $E$ be any subset of $\mathcal P(W)$ which is the power set of $W$, and let $F$ be the filter generated by $E$. Show that $F$ is the set of all $X \in \mathcal P(W)$ such that either $X = W$ or for some $Y_1,. . . , Y_n$ with each $Y_i \in E$, $Y_1 \cap ...   \cap Y_n \subseteq X$.

Now I am able to show one part of the problem.

Call the set of all $X \in \mathcal P(W)$ such that either $X = W$ or for some $Y_1,. . . , Y_n$ with each $Y_i \in E$, $Y_1 \cap ...   \cap Y_n \subseteq X$ as $S$.

We also know that from definition, $F=\cap \{G|G\text{ is filter over } W,E\subseteq G\}$

Now if $X\in S$ then say $X=W$ and so by definition of filter $X$ is in every filter and thus $X\in F$

Otherwise $X\neq W$ and for some $Y_1,. . . , Y_n$ with each $Y_i \in E$, $Y_1 \cap ...   \cap Y_n \subseteq X$. Take $G$ to be a filter over $W$ and $E\subseteq G$. So $Y_i\in G$ and since $G$ is filter we have $Y_1 \cap ...   \cap Y_n \in G$. But $Y_1 \cap ...   \cap Y_n \subseteq X$ means $X\in G$. hence $X\in F$

So we have $S\subseteq F$.

Am I correct upto this part?

And now I have stuck in the opposite direction. I am not finding a way to show this. Perhaps I am missing something or there may be some other approach to solve the problem. I am completely stuck here.

Please help me to solve this problem. Thnx in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HINT: What you’ve done so far is fine. To finish the proof, you need only show that $S$ is a filter containing $E$, since it will then follow immediately that $F\subseteq S$.

Comment: Thank you very much for your hint. I think I have got it now. To put $E$ in $S$ we will choose $A\in E$  and choosing a single  $Y_1=A$ it is evident that  $Y\in S$. and hence $E\subseteq S$ Am I correct?

Comment: @usermath: You’re welcome. Yes, that’s correct.

Comment: Thnx a lot for your help.

Comment: @usermath: You’re welcome.